# Get time difference in eloquent. Laravel

Tags: datetime, eloquent, laravel-5

There's a table *'comment'* with column time-stamp. I want the time difference from the date comment has been created to current date and time like created '5 Days ago' somewhat. I have no idea how to do that from eloquent.
My controller is:

```
  public function show($id)
        {
            $vehicles=vehicles::findorfail($id);

            $user=users::where('id',$vehicles->Users_id)->get()->first();

            //adding view count

            $viewad=ads::where('Vehicleid',$id)->get()->first();
            $viewcount=$viewad->views;

            $ad = ads::find($viewad->id);
            $ad->views=$viewcount+1;
            $ad->save();

            $comments=comment::where('vehicles_id',$id)->get();
   return view('Bike.show',compact('vehicles','user','viewcount','comments'));
  }
```

How can i accomplish this task? Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Laravel uses Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Comment: This has been done fro controller. Isn't there anyway to do via view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Carbon. See [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) for the details.

```
$comments=comment::where('vehicles_id',$id)->get();
$today=Carbon::now();
```

and the view:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
{{$comment->name}} Created {{$today->diffForHumans($comment->time_stamp)}}
@endforeach
```

You have to import the namespace to use Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: It worked but, instead of ago, it is showing 13 hours after. I used created_at instead of time_stamp as it only showed 1 seconds ago.
`Commented {{$today->diffForHumans($comment->created_at)}}`

Comment: @Anon oh. it is  `{{$comment->time_stamp->diffForHumans($today)}}`

Comment: It throws error of Call to a member function diffForHumans() on null

Comment: @Anon `$today->$comment->time_stamp->diffForHumans();` may be. See the link for details.

Comment: {{$today->diffForHumans($comment->created_at->addMonth())}} worked for me. Thanks Sanzeeb!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it available in the view the easiest way is to make an attribute accessor in the model.

First import Carbon at the start of the file `use Carbon\Carbon;`.

Then create the attribute accessor in your `Comment` model:

```
public function getTimeDifferenceAttribute()
{
    return $this->time_stamp->diffForHumans(Carbon::now);
}
```

(I've used `snake_case` for the timestamp attribute name because the `kebab-case` version you used isn't valid in PHP variable names.)

Then it's available from a comment as `$comment->time_difference`.

EDIT:

This answer assumed that the model was treating `time_stamp` as a date. If this is not the case you should also add `protected $dates = ['time_stamp'];` to the model.